# Virtual DOM and real DOM batch operation interval

Tags: reactjs, vue.js, frame-rate

I am learning 2 popular frameworks: React.js and Vue.js. The both frameworks use Virtual DOM in order to batch browser DOM manipulation for saving us from unnecessary re-flow/repaint.

I am curious here about batch operation interval (how many times per second/FPS Virtual DOM would batch all changes to real DOM for update UI), do you guys know about this ?

Comment: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Async-Update-Queue

Comment: `Then, in the next event loop “tick”, Vue flushes the queue and performs the actual (already de-duped) work.` So It will update in the next “tick”, when the queue is flushed and **what is fixed time in milliseconds for next "tick" because I am expecting 60FPS**

Comment: It's asynchronous. It's not done in terms of frame rates. It's done when there are updates to handle and the program allows an async operation. The rate would be limited by the hardware.

Comment: So assuming that Vue has 2000 changes (already de-duped) in the queue, does it try to flush **2000 changes all at once in next "tick" (could be time-consuming)** or splitting changes into **several chunks and flush in several next "tick"**

Comment: It will flush the queue. It will be time-consuming in any case.